# MacOS malloc debug log gets deleted on process exit

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, malloc

I've been reading Apple's canonical article on userland debugging, [TN2124](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2124/_index.html), trying to debug a crashing problem with a (self-written) `.dylib` loaded as a plugin into a proprietary main binary with no debugging symbols, [TeamSpeak 3](http://teamspeak.com).

I learned that if you set the environment variable `MallocStackLoggingNoCompact` to `1`, `malloc()` and `free()` and a lot of other details about memory allocation get spewed to a quickly-growing "stack log" file.

However, it appears that as soon as the process exits, MacOS *deletes* the stack log file, meaning that it's completely useless for debugging a crasher bug (when you suspect that it may be caused by e.g. a double free, but you aren't sure).

For example: `sh(4072,0x7fffb9d323c0) malloc: stack logs deleted from /Users/me/Documents/stack-logs.4072.10f244000.sh.ylfxwm.index` gets printed to stderr the instant the process crashes (exits). It happens if the process exits normally, too.

If it's deleted, I can't use it. How can I prevent MacOS from deleting the log file when the process exits?

Comment: I found a way with debugging symbols: just use a debugger and break the program right before it exits, then use leaks with the PID of the debugged process. I couldn't get leaks to work without debugging symbols for some reason.